# Python Equivalent to Ruby's #each_cons?

Tags: python, ruby, enumerable, equivalent

Is there a Pythonic equivalent to Ruby's `#each_cons`?

In Ruby you can do this:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]
array.each_cons(2).to_a
=> [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this? Just wondering ;)

Comment: I'm doing a moving average of a list. #each_cons is how I would do it in Ruby, so I'm wondering how Pythonistas do it.

Comment: For a truly equivalent to Ruby's each_cons, use [`toolz.itertoolz.sliding_window()`](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/toolz/itertoolz.html#sliding_window).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For such things, `itertools` is the module you should be looking at:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Then:

```
>>> list(pairwise([1, 2, 3, 4]))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

For an even more general solution, consider this:

```
def split_subsequences(iterable, length=2, overlap=0):
    it = iter(iterable)
    results = list(itertools.islice(it, length))
    while len(results) == length:
        yield results
        results = results[length - overlap:]
        results.extend(itertools.islice(it, length - overlap))
    if results:
        yield results
```

This allows arbitrary lengths of subsequences and arbitrary overlapping. Usage:

```
>> list(split_subsequences([1, 2, 3, 4], length=2))
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>> list(split_subsequences([1, 2, 3, 4], length=2, overlap=1))
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

Comment: Python 3: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html - Py2: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

Comment: The general solution here does not behave like `each_cons` when you have a sequence with insufficient length (each_cons returns nil). The implementation in snipsnipsnip's answer seems more appropriated in this regard.

Comment: `list(split_subsequences([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], length=3, overlap=1))` should return `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]` and not `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6]]`.

Answer (score 23):

I don't think there is one, I looked through the built-in module `itertools`, which is where I would expect it to be. You can simply create one though:

```
def each_cons(xs, n):
    return [xs[i:i+n] for i in range(len(xs)-n+1)]
```

Comment: +1 for generic answer. Mine worked for `2`, but after modifying it for an arbitrary `cons`, it looked like yours.

Comment: In general solutions that work also for iterables are preferrable, but well, it's ok for sequences. Nit-picking: `x` is a collection, so better `xs` (naming is very important, even in examples. I'd even say it's *more* important in examples :)).

Answer (score 6):

My solution for lists (Python2):

```
import itertools
def each_cons(xs, n):
    return itertools.izip(*(xs[i:] for i in xrange(n)))
```

**Edit:** With Python 3 [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) is no longer, so you use plain [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def each_cons(xs, n):
    return zip(*(xs[i:] for i in range(n)))
```

Comment: This solution does not work if the argument xs is a generator, moreover it is not really lazy because of the slice `xs[i:]`.

Comment: You're right, I could write `islice(xs, i, None)` instead of `xs[i:]`. I preferred latter for some reason: a) The question was about lists. b) [I use `each_cons` for lists most of the time](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureGeneralization). c) In case `xs` is a list, sliced lists will have shared memory, so it may be memory efficient than doing it lazy.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I know. =) It's just that Ruby's `#each_cons` works for everything, so I thought I should point it out. I've posted a lazy solution for those who need one.

Comment: For a moment I deleted my answer, seeing that your approach adding islice worked with an `xrange()`. It still failed with a plain generator, though. This little piece of code is very beautiful, thanks again for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

A quick one-liner:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

out = [a[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(a) - 1)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Python can surely do this. If you don't want to do it so eagerly, use itertool's islice and izip. Also, its important to remember that normal slices will create a copy so if memory usage is important you should also consider the itertool equivalents.

`each_cons = lambda l: zip(l[:-1], l[1:])`

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** Nevermind my answer below, just use [`toolz.itertoolz.sliding_window()`](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/toolz/itertoolz.html#sliding_window) -- it will do the right thing.

---

For a truly lazy implementation that preserves the behavior of Ruby's `each_cons` when the sequence/generator has insufficient length:

```
import itertools
def each_cons(sequence, n):
    return itertools.izip(*(itertools.islice(g, i, None)
                          for i, g in
                          enumerate(itertools.tee(sequence, n))))
```

Examples:

```
>>> print(list(each_cons(xrange(5), 2)))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
>>> print(list(each_cons(xrange(5), 5)))
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)]
>>> print(list(each_cons(xrange(5), 6)))
[]
>>> print(list(each_cons((a for a in xrange(5)), 2)))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Note that the tuple unpacking used on the arguments for izip is applied to a tuple of size `n` resulting of `itertools.tee(xs, n)` (that is, the "window size"), and not the sequence we want to iterate.

Answer (score 2):

Close to @Blender's solution but with a fix:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = 2
out = [a[i:i + n] for i in range(len(a) - n + 1)]
# => [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Or

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = 3
out = [a[i:i + n] for i in range(len(a) - n + 1)]
# => [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Python 3 version of Elias's code

```
from itertools import islice, tee

def each_cons(sequence, n):
    return zip(
        *(
            islice(g, i, None)
            for i, g in
            enumerate(tee(sequence, n))
        )
    )

$ ipython

...    

In [2]: a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [3]: list(each_cons(a_list, 2))
Out[3]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]

In [4]: list(each_cons(a_list, 3))
Out[4]: [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]

In [5]: list(each_cons(a_list, 5))
Out[5]: [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]

In [6]: list(each_cons(a_list, 6))
Out[6]: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation using `collections.deque`. This supports arbitrary generators as well

```py
from collections import deque

def each_cons(it, n):
    # convert it to an iterator
    it = iter(it)

    # insert first n items to a list first
    deq = deque()
    for _ in range(n):
        try:
            deq.append(next(it))
        except StopIteration:
            for _ in range(n - len(deq)):
                deq.append(None)
            yield tuple(deq)
            return

    yield tuple(deq)

    # main loop
    while True:
        try:
            val = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            return
        deq.popleft()
        deq.append(val)
        yield tuple(deq)
```

Usage:

```py
list(each_cons([1,2,3,4], 2))
# => [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]

# This supports generators
list(each_cons(range(5), 2))
# => [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]

list(each_cons([1,2,3,4], 10))
# => [(1, 2, 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None)]
```